# Ansible module returns non json data

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, json

Ansible Azure module returns the data in a weird format `Double single quoted characters`.

`''network_interface_names'': [''Ubuntu915'']`

As a result I can't use this anywhere to filter other resources.

Any idea what can be done to fix this or make it json?

```
  - name: Get facts by name
    azure_rm_virtualmachine_info:
      resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
      name: "{{ vm_name }}"
    register: azure_vm_info

  - name: "Network interface List"
    set_fact:
      azure_vm_network_interface: "{{ [ azure_vm_info.vms[0].network_interface_names  ] }}"

  - name: Print Azure VM Info
    debug:
      msg: "Azure VM INFO: {{ azure_vm_info.vms[0].network_interface_names }}"
```

Output:

```
   TASK [Print Azure VM Info] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
   ok: [localhost] =>
   msg: 'Azure VM INFO: [''Ubuntu915'']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In `ansible.cfg` I had set `stdout_callback = yaml`. changing it `json` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

`ansible-playbook` standard output is for human consumption, not for machine parsing.

Typically you would take task outputs from `register:` variables, and send them through filters, use in expressions, or otherwise process them.

Or, [`ansible-runner`](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy) has a well defined output format. It exists to power AWX/Tower.